# how to get data from firebase use reduxsaga

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux-saga

I am getting data from firebase, I use redux saga.

RN 0.59
firebase 5.10.0

```
function* getInfoPostSaga() {
  try {
    console.log("test");

    yield call(
      firebaseNana
      .database()
      .ref("posts/")
      .on("value", snap => {
          const info = snap.val();
          console.log(info); // yes, i got it
          return info;
        })
    );
    console.log("data"); // not print 'data'
    console.log(info); // i can not get info Object

    yield put(getPostRequestSuccess(info));
  } catch (error) {
yield put(getPostRequestError(error));
  }
 }
```